# What is the easiest way to have a local LAMP installation for web development on mac OS X?

Tags: macos, webserver, lamp

I'm new to mac os x. In the Windows XP world, there are packages available, like easyPHP, wampserver, uniformserver, that enable you to have a local webserver complete with php, mysql configured via an automatic installer. Really handy.

I need the same on my new mac. I know mac os x comes with a local webserver. Is this already with php, mysql preinstalled?

I'd like to have you guys advise on the easiest way to have this local lamp so that i can continue developing on this nice and shiny machine.

thanks!

Comment: Isn't the L in LAMP linux? :P

Comment: The 'L' is pretty much irrelevant: most php code (the 'P') doesn't care about the OS as long the PHP interpreter functions with the right web server and db.

Comment: ... though occasionally you will need to pull something off of the file system.

Comment: Unix -> BSD -> FreeBSD -> NeXTSTEP -> Mac OS X. Both Linux and OS X are essentially Unix, and at the command line they're practically identical. The only major difference is that OS X's support for the X window system is horrid, but this doesn't affect web development really.

Comment: @Chris unless you wanna use the ln command... in which case source and target are reversed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question : What means LAMP ?

Answer : Linux Apache MySQL PHP

Q: and if this was running on a Mac ?

A : try [MAMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mamp)

Comment: Great call. MAMP was exactly what i was searching for. it even allows to use the 80 port so the built-in apache does not get in the way.

Answer (score 3):

XAMPP is also an excellent choice

Answer (score 1):

http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/php_leopard.php

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mac-os-x-installation.html

Answer (score 1):

OS X comes with php and apache installed already. It doesn't have mysql installed by default, but you can easily download the Mac OS X version from [the mysql website](http://www.mysql.com/) in either the tarball version or a package version.

Comment: As a side note, OS X also comes with Perl, Python, and Ruby if you want to do web development with another scripting language. It doesn't come with a C compiler or a make program, but if you install the (free) developer's tools you'll get GCC and GNU Make, which you'll need to install MySQL.

Comment: It comes with a full rails setup too (in 10.5)... and I'd say it does "come with" the compiler, it's just not installed by default :)

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X is -- essentially -- Linux.

Mac OS X already contains Apache.  Turn on file sharing and you'll turn on Apache.

You'll need to download and install MySQL for Mac OS X.  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html

You'll need to edit the httpd.conf to enable mod_apache.

Answer (score 0):

Five years later, i believe this question and existing answers still reading by some newcomers.

Personally, i strongly recommend using **[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)** to have a perfect development environment on mac os x. Not only PHP, homebrew opens wide all the doors to the open source toolkit/library/application heaven.

Here is my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095942/problems-compile-phalcon-on-osx-10-9/25100138#25100138) related with this subject.