# PHP setup for Mac

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the easiest way to have a local LAMP installation for web development on mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714528/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-have-a-local-lamp-installation-for-web-development-on)

I am new to PHP and I'm not really looking for help with the scripting but actually how to get set up.  I am really confused by the amount of different threads on sites..

Firstly as stated in my title I am a Mac user and use Coda for all my sites but want to immerse my self in to the world of server side programming.

Do I need a server to start?  Is there a way to use my own Mac as a server to practice my scripts and develop sites locally before FTP-ing to my web host.

I am aware of Apache and mySQL but but not really sure how they work?  And what the software actual is used for.  Appreciate any will help for me the novice.

I am writing this while being at work so apologise for the possibly unclear/rushed request.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple environment, try out [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html):

> XAMPP is an easy to install Apache distribution containing MySQL, PHP and Perl. XAMPP is really very easy to install and to use - just download, extract and start.

Yes, it's really that simple. Just follow the tutorial here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html#849

Answer (score 1):

Try Googling MAMP, they have a basic version and a professional one that can handle multiple hosts which can be useful as you embark on more projects.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP packages can make it quite simple:

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, given a solid workstation with enough ram, virtualization is the best way to go.  Your application will ultimately be running on a server, most probably *nix based, so why not develop against your target?  The mac has popular virtualization packages like Parallels and Vmware fusion that sell like hotcakes from what I've seen, and there's virtualbox which is a free alternative.

You can also simulate things using virtualization like a cluster of servers, that is near impossible with a single workstation install.  In my experience there is something to be said for not gumming up your workstation with a bunch of server processes that you have to start and stop all the time or worse are eating up memory and processing power.  Having that all in a virtual machine that you can run when you want and disable when you don't is a great alternative to that.